# Discord.py - how to shut down a bot properly and disconnect from databases

Tags: discord.py

I am developing a discord bot and currently managing data in memory. Everything is ok but I need to move over to using databases to store data. So my question is how do you properly 'shut down' a bot and disconnect from the database?

To give an example, suppose I have code like this

```
import os, sqlite3
import random
from dotenv import load_dotenv

from discord.ext import commands

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
dbcon=None

@bot.event
async def on_ready(): #Q1
    print(f'{bot.user.name} has connected to Discord!')
    dbcon = sqlite3.connect('example.db')

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

I understand that the last line starts the bot, which will run and listens to events and respond to them. But I am not sure:

- Q1: should I init the database in the `on_connect` method instead of `on_ready`? I read the API but still I am not sure
- how do I implement a method that can be used to 'turn off' the bot, that method should shut down the sql connection `dbcon`? Is this through the `on_disconnect` method?
  ]

Comment: The solution depends on what your hosting your bot on. What are you hosting your bot on?

Comment: I am currently testing it on a company server. This is just a PC with an IP address